# php fputcsv saving as a binary file

Tags: php, binaryfiles, fputcsv

Why is `fputcsv($handle1, $tmp);` saving as a binary file? I've used this tons of times and never seen this.

Here's an example of what's in a `$tmp` array:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => AHCYL2
    [1] => Animals
    [2] => 6
    [3] => Vertebrates
    [4] => 6
    [5] => Eukaryota
    [6] => 6
    [7] => Chordata
    [8] => 6
    [9] => Cells
    [10] => 4
)
```

Here's the full code, which in related applications produced a CSV rather than binary file.

```
if ( ($handle1 = fopen($storage."aggregate_mesh_gene_top5_php.csv", "w") ) !== FALSE) {

        foreach($genes_top_5 as $gene => $mesh_arr){

            $tmp = [$gene];

            foreach($mesh_arr as $k => $v){

                $tmp[] = $k;
                $tmp[] = $v;
            }

            fputcsv($handle1, $tmp);

        }
}
fclose($handle1);
```

Here's what the aggregate_mesh_gene_top5_php.csv file looks like

[image]

Comment: Because file opened in binary mode?

Comment: @u_mulder i've never seen this be an issue before. `if ( ($handle1 = fopen($storage."aggregate_mesh_gene_top5_php.csv", "w") ) !== FALSE)`

Comment: Can you show the main part of the code and show the resultant CSV file to show what the result is.

Comment: What qualifies as a "binary" file in this case?

Comment: @NigelRen added main code.

Comment: @Sammitch added what the file looks like.

Comment: Yep there's a whole bunch of null bytes and nonsense in that file, and they're probably in your source data too.